# How to print in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I am still new to `asp.net`. I know how to print in windows application using both of these methods:

1. **Crystal report :** It is very easy but I tried to do it in asp.net but I could not. Once I tried to do it I can not add the values as I do in the windows application. It only asks for connection to database. How can I do that in the asp.net?
2. **Printing document :** Using the variables:

   `PrintDocument bill_doc = new PrintDocument();`

How can I use this in asp.net?

Waiting for your kind feedback.

BR//

Comment: Calling an method that is supposed to create a print document object on the server will try to print ON the server. You need to use client side (browser) logic to pop the print dialog to give remote clients connected via a browser, the ability to print to their printers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<asp:Button ID="printButton" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" />
```